# How can I get YAML to evaluate a numerical expression

Tags: yaml

I have the following expression in YAML:

```
service: mqtt.publish
data:
  topic: zigbee2mqtt/Bathroom_Dimmer/set
  payload:{"brightness_step": 150-{{state_attr('light.Bathroom_Dimmer','brightness')|int}} }
```

It outputs:

```
Message 7 received on zigbee2mqtt/Bathroom_Dimmer/set at 10:07 PM:

{"brightness_step": 150-255}
```

How can I get it to output "-105" instead of "150-255"?

EDIT:
I think that automations in Home Assistant use the Jinja2 engine. The double brackets make it evaluate. So the problem was that the 150 was not in the brackets. Adding extra brackets did not work, so it seems they cannot be nested.

Comment: That's not just YAML, whether you can do that and how will depend on what's interpreting the string.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Sorry if it is not very clear, I'm very new at this. It is an automation in Home Assistant. All I know is that is it YAML code. Is there anything I can try?

Comment: YAML is just markup, not code. The value in YAML is just `"150-{{state_attr('light.Bathroom_Dimmer','brightness')|int}}"`, then _something_ is parsing and evaluating it. You'll have to find out what and how.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I see that I have a lot of digging to do before I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

YAML is not code, so you can't expect a generalised behaviour of evaluating any kind of expression. It's up to the application that uses that data to decide what to do with it and you *may* find that some applications do support an expression syntax within YAML.

I'm guessing this is something to do with a [ZigBee config file](https://www.zigbee2mqtt.io/guide/usage/mqtt_topics_and_messages.html#zigbee2mqtt-bridge-request) which I have never used, but I don't see any evidence that it supports expressions. Do you have any reason to believe that it does? If so, this behaviour comes from the application, not from YAML.

Comment: You are right, it is a Zigbee automation in Home Assistant. I am a bit surprised it did not evaluate because it did evaluate state_attr{} part. Thanks for the reply, I'll keep digging for a while :)

Comment: @Orbit ah - I missed this point - the double parentheses do suggest an expression; what happens if you enclose both terms in the `{{ }}`? This resembles a [liquid](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/) expression, I wonder whether there is some preprocessing being applied in this tool...?

Comment: I think it is processed by Jinja2. It is also possible to use a 'template' for more advances use, and the manual states that it is then processed by Jinja2. Jinja2 code seems to work. I have moved the whole expression in to the brackets and that did it :). Adding an extra pair of brackets around both just gave an error. Thanks for the help :)